# How often did a name appeared in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have the following dataframe

```
    d = {'Name': ['Bob','Bob','Bob', 'Bob','Bob', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam'], 
     'Start_date': ['2017-12-31', '2017-12-31', '2017-12-31', '2017-12-31', '2017-12-31','2019-02-28', '2019-02-28', '2019-02-28', '2020-05-31', '2020-05-31', '2020-05-31', '2020-05-31', '2020-05-31', '2020-05-31', '2020-05-31', '2020-05-31'],
     'Event_Date': ['2017-12-31', '2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31', '2018-04-30','2019-02-28', '2019-03-31', '2019-04-30', '2020-05-31', '2020-06-30', '2020-07-31', '2020-08-31', '2020-09-30', '2020-10-31', '2020-11-30', '2020-12-31']
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

And I would like to get the following output:

```
d = {'Name': ['Bob','Bob','Bob', 'Bob','Bob', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam'], 
     'Start_date': ['2017-12-31', '2017-12-31', '2017-12-31', '2017-12-31', '2017-12-31','2019-02-28', '2019-02-28', '2019-02-28', '2020-05-31', '2020-05-31', '2020-05-31', '2020-05-31', '2020-05-31', '2020-05-31', '2020-05-31', '2020-05-31'],
     'Date': ['2017-12-31', '2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31', '2018-04-30','2019-02-28', '2019-03-31', '2019-04-30', '2020-05-31', '2020-06-30', '2020-07-31', '2020-08-31', '2020-09-30', '2020-10-31', '2020-11-30', '2020-12-31'],
     'Count_occurence': [1, 2,3,4,5,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Comment: `df["Count_occurence"] = df.groupby("Name").cumcount() + 1`

Comment: wow thank you Andrej! It worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the pandas.Series.apply method. You could create a value_counts object and then apply a dictionary lookup. I've provided an example below, but I am afraid I cannot really discern what you're trying to count from the problem description.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Name': ['Bob','Bob','Bob', 'Bob','Bob', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam'], 
    'Start_date': ['2017-12-31', '2017-12-31', '2017-12-31', '2017-12-31', '2017-12-31','2019-02-28', '2019-02-28', '2019-02-28', '2020-05-31', '2020-05-31', '2020-05-31', '2020-05-31', '2020-05-31', '2020-05-31', '2020-05-31', '2020-05-31'],
    'Event_Date': ['2017-12-31', '2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31', '2018-04-30','2019-02-28', '2019-03-31', '2019-04-30', '2020-05-31', '2020-06-30', '2020-07-31', '2020-08-31', '2020-09-30', '2020-10-31', '2020-11-30', '2020-12-31'] }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
counts = df['Name'].value_counts()

df['count'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: counts[x])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

print(df)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer unfortunately this is wrong, this gives you in the new 'count' column the total number of times a name appeared. But I am interested in the total number that the name appeared til now. as in if Bob in the first row then count=1 then Bob second row so it counted bob twice count=2. If you put my above code in python it will be more clear what is being counted